# Result of while loop not increasing in value

Tags: python, while-loop

Newbie at python. I am writing a program to find the next perfect square if the input is a perfect square. My issue is that I cannot figure out why my while loop in determine_next_square is not actually increasing the value of test. The result is an infinite loop of the sane number (11.045...)

```
# return the next perfect square is input(sq) is a square, otherwise return -1

def isfloat(x): # tests to see if a variable is not a whole number
    try:
        a = float(x)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def isint(x): # tests to see if a variable is a whole number
    try:
        a = float(x)
        b = int(a)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return False
    else:
        return a == b
    
def find_next_square(sq):
    square = sq ** .5 # this square roots the input
    if isint(square) == True: # checks to see if square is a whole number
        print(square)
        determine_next_square(sq)     # since this is True, run determine_next_square
    else:           # if the input is not a perfect square, return -1
        print(-1)

def determine_next_square(sq):
        i = 1 # value to be added to
        plusone = sq + i # add the changing looped value to the initial input
        test = plusone ** .5 # calculate the new "inputs" square root
        while isfloat(test): # checks to see if test is a float. If true, continue on and add 1 to each check.
            print(test)
            i = i + 1 # should add 1 to plusone each loop,
            # after 1 gets added, this while loop should check the new value and equation to see if it is a whole number yet
            # why does this while loop not add 1 to i, and therefore increase the value of test?
        else:
            print(test ** 2)
            # this should print out the final result of test once it is a whole number and not a decimal, and squares it to get the answer.

sq = 121 # input


find_next_square(sq)



print('End')
```

Comment: I'd recommend stepping through this code with your debugger.  Inspect the values of `test` and `i` inside the loop, and your problem should become clear.

Comment: You only update 'i', but you never update 'test' in the loop, so if it enters the loop it will never exit.

Comment: Since test is ultimately modified by i, shouldn't I not need to modify test?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a tip from 0x5453 I was able to figure it out!

Original block of code:

```
def determine_next_square(sq):
        i = 1 # value to be added to
        plusone = sq + i # add the changing looped value to the initial input
        test = plusone ** .5 # calculate the new "inputs" square root
        while isfloat(test): # checks to see if test is a float. If true, continue on and add 1 to each check.
            print(test)
            i = i + 1 # should add 1 to plusone each loop,
            # after 1 gets added, this while loop should check the new value and equation to see if it is a whole number yet
            # why does this while loop not add 1 to i, and therefore increase the value of test?
        else:
            print(test ** 2)
            # this should print out the final result of test once it is a whole number and not a decimal, and squares it to get the answer.
```

I ended up redefining test inside of the loop so that it gets modified inside of the loop. There may be a better way to do it, but it works.

New code:

```
def determine_next_square(sq):
        i = 1 # value to be added to
         # add the changing looped value to the initial input
        test = (sq + i) ** .5 # calculate the new "inputs" square root
        while isint(test) == False: # checks to see if test is a whole number, while false run the loop.
            i = i + 1
            test = (sq + i) ** .5 # redfined test so that 1 is added to it every loop inside of the while statement. 
            # after 1 gets added, this while loop should check the new value and equation to see if it is a whole number yet
        else:
            print(test ** 2)
            # this should print out the final result of test once it is a whole number and not a decimal, and squares it to get the answer.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your code. The issue you're asking about happens because you never change `test` in your `while` loop. So change

```
while isfloat(test):
    print(test)
    i = i + 1
```

to

```
while isfloat(test):
    print(test)
    i = i + 1
    plusone = sq + i
    test = plusone ** .5
```

This will fix the issue you're talking about. And I think you're confused about how variables work in Python. For example, right above this `while` loop, you defined

```
test = plusone ** .5
```

but that doesn't mean that `test` will *always* be equivalent to `plusone ** .5`, because if you change `plusone` after this line executes, Python will not automatically update the value of `test`.

Your second issue is the condition you're checking in your `while` loop. Your `isfloat` function will succeed when passed an `int`, so you should change

```
while isfloat(test):
```

to something like

```
while not isint(test):
```